# WIX - Finding out the number of cores during install

Tags: wix

During the install of our product we need to know how many cores the CPU has.  Does Wix have this capability?.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why the hell would you need to know this at install time? At run time, to spawn a reasonable number of threads, sure, but at install time?!

Comment: Perhaps there is a requirement to only allow installation if a certain number of cores?  Questionable, agreed.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing native in the Windows Installer or WiX to support this. Windows Installer has a set of Hardware Properties such as the Intel, Intel64 (Itanium) and Msix64 (AMD/Intel) properties but nothing for core count.

You'd need a custom action (typically c++ or C# ) to get the information and set a property for use later in your installer.  Exact details depend on the language you pick.

Comment: Ok, thanks Christopher.  We will use c or hopefully inline vbscript to get it. For those curious, we need the # of cores as we are installing a real time OS called RTX alongside windows.  We need to explicitly tell RTX how many cores are dedicated to it. Steve.

Comment: I intentionally didn't mention VBScript because the ActiveScript host in Windows Installer is very fragile. It's best to avoid.

Comment: Christopher, Thanks for your tips. So lets say i write a small c++ .exe to return the number of cores.  How would i get that number back into wix?, assuming my .exe is called as a CustomAction.  Thanks Steve

Comment: You create a DLL not an EXE.  WiX has a C++ Custom Action project template in Visual Studio that can help you get started.  You use MsiSetProperty() to pass the data back to Windows Installer.  You don't get it back to WiX because WiX is merely an authoring tool to create a Windows Installer database.

Answer (score 0):

A possible non-custom action solution: there are Registry keys `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\0`, `HKLM\HARDWARE\DESCRIPTION\System\CentralProcessor\1`, etc., one for each of the cores.

If you wanted, for example, to condition something on having at least four cores, set an MSI property via a Registry search for one of the values in the `...\CentralProcessor\3` key (the default Registry value is usually empty, so use one of the other values like `Identifier`).

That will set the property if and only if there are at least 4 cores. You can then use the presence or absence of this MSI property to condition whatever action depends on having enough cores.